# Only one python program running (like Firefox)?

Tags: python, firefox, google-chrome, process

When I open Firefox, then run the command:

```
firefox http://somewebsite
```

the url opens in a new tab of Firefox (same thing happens with Chromium as well). Is there some way to replicate this behavior in Python? For example, calling:

```
processStuff.py file/url
```

then calling:

```
processStuff.py anotherfile
```

should not start two different processes, but **send a message** to the currently running program. For example, you could have info in one tabbed dialog box instead of 10 single windows.

Adding bounty for anyone who can describe **how** Firefox/Chromium do this in a cross-platform way.

Comment: There are different approaches depending on the platform.. What platform are you trying use it on?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The way Firefox does it is: the first instance creates a socket file (or a named pipe on Windows). This serves both as a way for the next instances of Firefox to detect and communicate with the first instance, and forward it the URL before dying. A socket file or named pipe being only accessible from processes running on the local system (as files are), no network client can have access to it. As they are files, firewalls will not block them either (it's like writing on a file).

Here is a naive implementation to illustrate my point. On first launch, the socket file `lock.sock` is created. Further launches of the script will detect the lock and send the URL to it:

```
import socket
import os

SOCKET_FILENAME = 'lock.sock'

def server():
    print 'I\'m the server, creating the socket'
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind(SOCKET_FILENAME)

    try:
        while True:
            print 'Got a URL: %s' % s.recv(65536)
    except KeyboardInterrupt, exc:
        print 'Quitting, removing the socket file'
        s.close
        os.remove(SOCKET_FILENAME)

def client():
    print 'I\'m the client, opening the socket'
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(SOCKET_FILENAME)
    s.send('http://stackoverflow.com')
    s.close()

def main():
    if os.path.exists(SOCKET_FILENAME):
        try:
            client()
        except (socket.error):
            print "Bad socket file, program closed unexpectedly?"
            os.remove(SOCKET_FILENAME)
            server()
    else:
        server()

main()
```

You should implement a proper protocol (send proper datagrams instead of hardcoding the length for instance), maybe using [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html), but this is beyond this question. The [Python Socket Programming Howto](http://docs.python.org/howto/sockets.html) might also help you. I have no Windows machine available, so I cannot confirm that it works on that platform.

Comment: Is that what the profile-directory/lock file does? Is there a way to do something similar in Python?

Comment: That's exactly what it does. I added some sample code to help you.

Comment: ls -la on the lock file ends with: .default/lock -> 192.168.0.69:+3178, does this mean the lock file is a link to a port?

Comment: The socketserver examples use socket.recv(number), I don't see how socketserver can solve the problem of hardcoded length. http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html

Comment: Actually the rifle / wfile interface get you readline() which lifts the hardcoded length requirement if the client sends '\n'-terminated strings (my network code here is crap for brevity's sake). I'm testing on Mac OS X, and an `ls -l` gives me `srwxr-xr-x   1 fred  staff     0 17 aoû 02:22 lock.sock`

Answer (score 8):

You could create a data directory where you create a "locking file" once your program is running, after having checked if the file doesn't exist yet.

If it exists, you should try to communicate with the existing process, which creates a socket or a pipe or something like this and communicates its address or its path in an appropriate way.

There are many different ways to do so, depending on which platform the program runs.

Answer (score 2):

While I doubt this is how Firefox / Chrome does it, it would be possible to archive your goal with out sockets and relying solely on the file system.  I found it difficult to put into text, so see below for a **rough** flow chart on how it could be done.  I would consider this approach similar to a cookie :).  One last thought on this is that with this it could be possible to store workspaces or tabs across multiple sessions.

**EDIT**
Per a comment, environment variables are not shared between processes.  All of my work thus far has been a single process calling multiple modules.  Sorry for any confusion.

[image: File System Message Relay]

Comment: Yes it would, I never claimed it was efficient ;). The only benefit I would see with this is that it would guarantee cross platform compatibility.  However I would agree with the others that the preferred way would be to use sockets.  My example here is just mimicking what a socket server would do in the 'listen' call.  If firewalls are a concern, I have used sockets on localhost and have had zero trouble on Win7 and Mac OS X.

Comment: environment variables aren't shared between processes.

Comment: @Winston: Good catch.  All of my examples I have been using with environment variables actually used a single process.  I was thinking I was spawning a new process, rather than just loading a new module.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use [multiprocessing connections](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Connection) with a [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html) to accomplish this.  Your script would just have to try to connect to the "remote" connection on localhost and if it's not available then it could start it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Very Basic is use sockets.
2. http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing
3. Use Threading, http://www.valuedlessons.com/2008/06/message-passing-conccurrency-actor.html

Example for Socket Programming: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52218-message-passing-with-socket-datagrams/

Comment: Sockets sound like a possibility, but couldn't they get blocked by a firewall?

Comment: You want to communicate between processes in your system, you can definitely disable it right?

Comment: If sockets are used, wouldn't it be possible for others on the local network/internet to call the Python module too? Seems it could be a possible security concern.

Comment: They can try to communicate with your app, but application will deny the incoming data.No one can mess with your app memory except your own app.