# Python: Execute function if this is the only process, otherwise send a message to the other process

Tags: python, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Only one python program running (like Firefox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992427/only-one-python-program-running-like-firefox)

I'm trying to write a program in Python to unpack large RAR archives.  This can easily be done using e.g. Chilkat's library for extracting.

However, I want to run only one unpacking process at a time. So the first time the Python program is executed, it just starts extracting, but if I start the program while the first process has yet to finish, I want to send a message to the existing process saying "hey, extract this once you're done with whatever you're doing right now".

I've looked at the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) library which looks promising with the `Queue` class and all, but I still have a hard time to understand where to start.

So my question is: how do I know whether an existing "extracter" process is already running and then how do I add stuff to that process' queue?

Answer (score 0):

A similiar question has been asked in [Only one python program running (like Firefox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6992427/296974). To adapt this to your needs, you should have the first process establish a FIFO, socket or something and then start its work. If the work is done, it has a look on the FIFO/socket/... to know if there is other stuff to do, and then go on or exit.

An improvement would be to have this program run in two threads, one for unpacking and one for serving the communication in order to have the "other" process know that the request has been accepted.